# Advantage of multi steps ODE methods over single step methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I wanna know what's the advantage of multi step ODE methods such as Adams-Bashforth over ordinary single step methods such Runge–Kutta, accuracy/time wise.

Comment: I think it's because a) while high order RK methods calculate several points "between" steps, multi-steps methods increase their accuracy by using points that were already calculated, therefore you have the same accuracy doing fewer calculations; and b) they can solve stiff differential equations, while RK methods usually require an absurdly small step size to provide an adequate solution. However, I can't remember exactly the reason for multi step methods being able to solve stiff equations.

Comment: @rafa11111 : Implicit one-step methods also deal with stiff problems. See the book of Hairer-Wanner: *Solving ODE II: Stiff and DAE problems*. Which has in general an extensive discussion about what "stiff" might mean and how diverse stability measures relate to it, and explains and compares different methods.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of **explicit** multistep methods compared to **explicit** Runge-Kutta lies in the fact that adding additional steps/function evaluations results (for reasonable multi-step) always in increase of the order of accuracy.

The classic examples thereof include the (explicit) Adams-Bashforth family, for which the the order of consistency $p$ is equal to the number of steps $k$ and the (explicit) Nyström methods with $p=k, k > 2$. [[1]](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-78862-1)

This is in stark contrast to explicit Runge-Kutta methods, for which the well-known Butcher-Barrier [[2]](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-rungekutta-processes-of-high-order/40DFE501CAB781C9AAE1439B6B8F481A), [[3]](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1965-19-091/S0025-5718-1965-0179943-X/S0025-5718-1965-0179943-X.pdf) kicks in at order 5, which states for orders $p \geq 5$ one needs at least $s \geq p + 1$ stages. This is innocent looking, but until now, there is no 7'th order accurate method with 8 stages known - the best known method uses 9 stages. This seems to become more severe for higher orders, as the best currently 8'th order explicit RK method requires 11 stages [[4]](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470753767).

Regarding **implicit** methods, the Butcher Barrier does not exist - in fact, there exist implicit methods with order $2s$ for all $s$ [[5]](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/zamm.19610411317), [[6]](https://www.abebooks.com/Numerical-Solution-Initial-Value-Problems-Ceschino/6760211466/bd), [[1]](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-78862-1).
**Implicit** multistep methods are much less attractive given that they are, in contrast to many implicit Runge-Kutta methods, not A-stable for orders above 2 (Second Dahlquist barrier [[7]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01963532)) and the order of consistency scales for most methods (e.g. Adams-Moulton, Backwards-Differentiation-Formulas(BDF)) only with $k+1$ instead of $2k$ as for some RK methods [[1]](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-78862-1).
These facts make them much less attractive compared to e.g. [Gauss-Legendre methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_method#cite_note-2).

---

It should be mentioned that there are of course many more considerations that one could make, e.g. the domains of absolute stability of explicit multistep and Runge-Kutta methods, storage efficiency, ease of varying timesteps, internal stability properties, combination of explicit and implicit methods, and so on.

But all of this would go far beyond a MSE post. If you want to dive deep, consider the books by Hairer & Wanner [[1]](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-78862-1), [[9]](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-05221-7), the book by Butcher [[4]](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470753767) or the one by Iserles [[10]](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/first-course-in-the-numerical-analysis-of-differential-equations/2B4E05F5CFC58CFDC7BBBC6D1150661B).

Comment: Stability regions are an important part of the argument. If you compare RK4 where the stability region includes a semi-circle of radius 2.5 and AB4 where such radius is 0.3, then for each RK4 step close to that boundary you need 8 AB steps for similar stability properties, which is twice the effort in function evaluations.

Comment: True, but I would like to avoid all these technical difficulties at that point and stay with the most general difference of these methods. Of course, what matters in practice is basically something like an error vs CPU-time / floating point operations - but then you get lost in the details, since you require stability regions of these methods, the most efficient implementation, ... It would be nice to link a study/review paper discussing this.